# Could a factless fact table also be a outrigger?

Tags: data-warehouse

Here is the relationship of these 3 tables

```
Product_T: Product_PK, Product-related attributes, Category_FK, SubCategory_FK
Category_T:Category_PK, Category-related attributes
SubCategory_T: Composite Key(Category_PK+SubCategory_PK)
```

that's all

I identify `SubCategory_T` as factless fact table because there is no measure, and I think `Category_T` is an outrigger, but is `SubCategory` also outrigger? can it be both factless fact table and outrigger?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. seems to have nothing to do with the tag `snowflake-data-warehouse`

Comment: I just want to clarify the concept ... I make up the above table so it's easier to understand the question

Comment: Maybe I do not understand why one would be interested in "factless fact tables" or "outriggers", I might need to do some reading, but in a decade of DB work I've not come across these terms (which doesn't mean anything) so yes..

Comment: right, so the question is good old KIMBELL terminology. So it still reads like a school question. Because if you know what these two terms mean, and are asking because you want to avoid the "badness"/"cost" of these concepts, then you would frame your question with why it matters to you. Where-as just asking if the terms overlap implies a lack of understanding of the terms (which is valid) but again why is the answer needed, might help frame the answer.